# Ubuntu installation, system failed to detect the iSCSI disk

Tags: iscsi

I configured a iSCSI SAN disk in HP DL360p G8 server BIOS using card HP 556FLR SP+. Storage used is IBM DS storage.
Bios can detect the disk, also I abled to install RHEL 6.7 over it. But, During Ubuntu installation, system failed to detect the iSCSI disk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed iscsi initiator and added iscsi targets? Just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am running into a very similar issue. I have gotten a step further by doing the following:
Once you get to the disk section of the install do Go Back which gives you a list of options, drop to a shell and run the command 'iscsistart -b'. That should read your initiator and target info from bios and connect to the SAN. Type exit to get back to the installer and go to the detect disks step. That should now show the iscsi disks. 
 
I was able to get everything installed just fine that way but now I am stuck after rebooting it seems that Ubuntu doesn't handle everything during the install and won't actually boot from the iscsi disk even though grub comes up fine. If anyone has any tips for that next part I would love to hear them!